# How can I make a Field not being editable after i put in some text?

Tags: .net, pdf, itext, textfield

as the title says i´ve got to fill text fields with data (what works perfectly) an make the fields uneditable.

I tried to achieve that using

`form.SetFieldProperty(key, key, TextField.READ_ONLY, Nothing)`

but I dont know what to put in as the last parameter and that line actually didnt do anything for me.
Another thing I tried to do was

```
form.RemoveField(key)
```

but that removed the field including the text so I had a blank pdf.

I have been looking for a solution now and then for quite a while now and i couldnt find anything to help me out in no tutorial or documentation.
Im actually quite surprised no one asked for that functionality before. Is it really because no one needs this funktion? Or is it because its so easy or obviously impossible using iTextSharp?

Answer (score 2):

<strike>My guess:</strike>

```
form.SetFieldProperty(key, key, TextField.READ_ONLY, TRUE)
```

Check out [here](http://kuujinbo.info/cs/itext_button_fields.aspx). They list a few different ways of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you very much tony.
Since i could find the solution in your link I post that here as answer to my own question.

Set FormFiel to read only:

```
form.SetFieldProperty(key, "setfflags", PdfFormField.FF_READ_ONLY, Nothing)
```